# Self-tracking entities Silverlight proxy generation

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

I’m developing a Silverlight 4 application using STE with EF4. I created a Silverlight project with all the Entity classes generated with my STE T4 template and build properly on VS. But when I add a WCF proxy with Visual Studio and check the “Reuse types in reference assemblies” (having a referece to my Client.Model assembly with all the STE) the visual studio proxy generator added some classes that are defined on my STE model, like ObjectList (List), ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties (Dictionary), ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties (Dictionary) and OriginalValuesDictionary (Dictionary).

So while I’m using visual Studio and trying to use those classes, there are two classes with the same name in two project, one coming from my STE model and the other one coming from the Visual Studio Proxy generation namespace.

Am I missing something? My project runs well and I’m able to request STE.

Thanks.

Luis Guerrero.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you're using different NameSpace between the Model-WCF-Silverlight Library.
You can try to force the name of the namespace in the Contract ( [DataContract(IsReference = true, Namespace = "your.namespace.here")]).
We had the same problem and now it runs Ok!